# Can't get output for Youtube videos using the youtube_it gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Been messing around with the Youtube_IT gem for the last couple of hours and I can't seem to get any videos to be displayed.

I have a videos controller with the following 
class VideosController < ApplicationController

```
require 'youtube_it'

  before_action :set_video, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
     @client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "DEV-KEY-HERE")
    @videos = Video.all
  end
```

For the index view, I've experimented with a lot of different methods.

```
<% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <%= client.videos_by(:query => "penguin") do |v| %>
    <%= v.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Nothing shows up. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
`@client.videos_by(:query => "penguin")` in the controller

And then in the view:

```
<%= client.each do |v| %>
  <%= v.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to ensure that you're actually connecting to YouTube and that you're not getting any error responses from the API. Also you should consider moving your developer key to an environment variable for security and also obfuscating it in your questio